# How can I iterate through a 2D list to just get the first index within each list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-for-loop

```
groups = [["Jobs", "Gates"], ["Newton", "Euclid"], ["Einstein", "Feynman"]]
 
# This outer loop will iterate over each list in the groups list
for group in groups:
  # This inner loop will go through each name in each list
  for name in group:
    print(name)`
```

Print out 'Jobs', 'Newton', 'Einstein'

Comment: Something like `for g in groups: print(g[0])`

Answer (score 2):

This is where list comprehensions are really nice in Python:

```
groups = [["Jobs", "Gates"], ["Newton", "Euclid"], ["Einstein", "Feynman"]]

print([group[0] for group in groups])
```

Result:

```
['Jobs', 'Newton', 'Einstein']
```

If you just want to do something with each individual first entry, you of course just do this:

```
for group in groups:
    print(group[0])
```

Or, without the indexing:

```
for (name, *__) in groups:
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like this:

```
groups = [["Jobs", "Gates"], ["Newton", "Euclid"], ["Einstein", "Feynman"]]
groups_only_first = [x[0] for x in groups]
print(groups_only_first)
```